# Upload Video files on Local Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload Video Files but on Folder not in Database, I have seen [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21480/Video-Uploader-Control-for-SQL-Server) but its saving video in Database.
I have tried  this code

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
     {
     }
}
```

but when I click on btn to upload, It gives me  error

> This web page is not available

However If I pick image or any other file(not audio or video) the same code works.
How can I upload Videos on Folder

I have this is web.config

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" />
```

Comment: No, Wil I be able to upload vidoes with IHttpHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Fixed, I had to use

```
 <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="20000" />
    </system.web>
```

in web.config file for Big files

Comment: Wonder how will it work with large video files?
Won't your browser freeze?

Comment: @NipunAmbastha I don't have to upload large videos, I have size limit of 20 MB :)

Comment: Indeed a lucky guy, we play around with 4 GB's of file in our project.